# How to put a colorbar into a matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have code which produces this figure:
[image]

In this plot, the color indicates the horizontal offset of the lower end of each line.  I would like a colorbar to appear in the legend (with 'start' and 'stop) which shows what the color means.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx


plt.clf()
plt.plot([0,100], [0,100], '--', linewidth=3, color='k', label = 'start')
plt.plot([100,100],[0,100], '-.', linewidth=3, color = 'k', label = 'stop')



jet = plt.get_cmap('jet') 
cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=99)
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=jet)

for offset in range(1,100):
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(offset)
    plt.plot([offset, 100], [0,100], color=colorVal)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So ideally I would have something looking like a standard colorbar, which ranges from 0 to 100, but appearing in the legend with a label `'offset'`.

Comment: I think one needs to reword this. You are looking for a way to place the colorbar at the position of the legend and have it surrounded by a border. Right?

Comment: Sort of.  I want it surrounded by the same border that surrounds `'start'` and '`stop'`.  In my real-world scenario I have a population that is at steady state (which I want to label explicitly).  Then something in the environment is changed, and each year the population changes a bit (I want the colors denoting the years).  Then there's a final steady state (which I also want to label explicitly)

Comment: There are two options: (1) You create an object which *looks* like a colorbar and use it as artist ("handle") for the legend. (2) You create a colorbar and position it where the legend is, and surround it by a grey box, such that it *looks* like it's in a legend. Both approaches are pretty hacky and non-trivial; to help a potential answerer here, you might at least want to start one of those and see how far you get.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer...  Both involve me getting outside my comfort zone, but I'll take a stab at it if I get a chance before my transpacific flight this evening.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code to accomplish this based on ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment approach (2).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

plt.clf()
plt.plot([0,100], [0,100], '--', linewidth=3, color='k', label = 'start')
plt.plot([100,100],[0,100], '-.', linewidth=3, color = 'k', label = 'stop')

jet = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=99)
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=jet)
scalarMap.set_array([])

for offset in range(1,100):
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(offset)
    plt.plot([offset, 100], [0,100], color=colorVal)

plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((0.1, 45), 40, 55, edgecolor='gray',
                                            linewidth=3, fill=False))
plt.gca().text(25, 90, "-- start")
plt.gca().text(25, 80, "-. stop")
plt.gca().text(15, 50, "  offset")

cax = fig.add_axes([0.18, 0.48, 0.03, 0.35])

plt.colorbar(scalarMap, cax = cax, ticks=[range(0, 100, 10)],
                                            orientation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image: screen shot]